# Trying to Bind List<T> to CheckedListBox in WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I am using WinForms C#
Is there any way to get following behavior:

1. bind List to CheckedListBox
2. When I add elements to list CheckedList box refereshes
3. When I change CheckedListBox the list changes

I tried to do the following:

Constructor code:

```
checkedlistBox1.DataSource = a;
checkedlistBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
checkedlistBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Field:

`List<Binder> a = new List<Binder> { new Binder { Name = "A" } };`

On button1 click:

```
private void butto1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a.Add(new Binder{Name = "B"});
    checkedListBox1.Invalidate();
    checkedListBox1.Update();
}
```

But the view does not update .

Thank You.

Comment: is the list box big enough to contain the new checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things you may wish to look at:

1. Use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)
2. Add a [BindableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx) to your *Name* property

Comment: To make an 'a' BindingList ? BindableAttribute  on 'a'?

Comment: @Sergey Kucher - antisanity provided two links for you. There's a comprehensive code examples at the links if you're unsure of what they meant.

Answer (score 7):

Change this line:

```
List<Binder> a = new List<Binder> { new Binder { Name = "A" } };
```

to this:

```
BindingList<Binder> a = new BindingList<Binder> { new Binder { Name = "A" } };
```

It will just work without any other changes.

The key is that [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) implements [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx), which will notify the control when the list changes. This allows the CheckedListBox control to update its state. This is two-way data binding.

Also, you could change these two lines:

```
checkedListBox1.Invalidate();
checkedListBox1.Update();
```

to this (more readable and essentially does the same thing):

```
checkedListBox1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your `List<Bender>` need to be some kind of observable collection, like `ObservableCollection<Bender>` instead?

Comment: Could be , could you please give me some code example of what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of binding a checked listbox is:

```
List<YourType> data = new List<YourType>();
checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<YourType>(data);
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(YourType.Name);
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = nameof(YourType.ID);
```

Note to self.

The issue i have every time binding it is that the properties **DataSource**, **DisplayMember** and **ValueMember** are **not suggested by intellisense** and i get confused.